# JPA could not locate named parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I keep getting the following error: "*could not locate named parameter [articleCommentId]*" but it doesn't make sense to me because to me the named parameter is very much in place.

```
public ArticleCommentForDisplay getCommentByArticleCommentId(BigInteger articleCommentId) {

    String queryString = "select c.article_comment_id,  "
            + "       c.article_id,  "
            + "       c.parent_comment_id, "
            + "       p.nickname, "
            + "       c.title,  "
            + "       c.comment, "
            + "       c.person_id, "
            + "       c.confirmed_user, "
            + "       c.comment_depth, "
            + "       c.moderation_rank, "
            + "       c.moderation_reason, "
            + "       c.hide, "
            + "       c.hide_reason, "
            + "       c.session_id, "
            + "       c.confirmation_uuid, "
            + "       c.created_timestamp, "
            + "       c.created_by_id, "
            + "       c.updated_timestamp, "
            + "       c.updated_by_id, "
            + "       c.update_action, "
            + "       null as comment_path "
            + "from article_comment c "
            + "   join person p "
            + "       on p.person_id = c.person_id "
            + "where c.article_comment_id = :articleCommentId; ";

    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryString, "ArticleCommentMap");
    query.setParameter("articleCommentId", articleCommentId);

    List <ArticleCommentForDisplay> articleComments = new ArrayList<>();
    articleComments = query.getResultList();
    ArticleCommentForDisplay theComment = articleComments.get(0);

    return (theComment);

}
```

Here is an extract of the stack trace with the relevant error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [articleCommentId]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:72)
    at com.extremelatitudesoftware.content.ArticleCommentFacade.getCommentByArticleCommentId(ArticleCommentFacade.java:293)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I bet it is due to the extra `;` in your query string.

SQL/HQL does not need to be terminated by semicolon

Comment: That was it. The strange this is that on another native query there was no problem with this. But with that one, the parameter is in the middle of the query (the root select on a recursive query). I guess I just included it there and it worked. Being human I only remembered that last thing that worked, because on the few other native queries I needed I didn't include the semi-colon. And of course they work. @CycDemo's answer I found is technically correct, another answer showed the spec stating this. But for Postgres + hibernate named parameters seem to work and make more understandable code.

Comment: You saved my day, even ChatGPT does not know about it.

Answer (score 8):

The named parameters is not defined for native queries in `JPA Specification`.

Replace

```
where c.article_comment_id = :articleCommentId;
```

with

```
where c.article_comment_id = ?1;
....
query.setParameter(1, articleCommentId)
```

Comment: Yes, this is in the spec. I researched this when I saw your answer and found another answer that quoted that part of the spec. So  point to you. But for Postgres + hibernate it tolerates named parameters. And named parameters make the code more readable. So I'll stick with them. Good pointer though.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was an extra `'` in the sql query. Oh my gosh, kept looking until my eyes nearly pooooopped out `-)

So, ensure that you don't have anything "*extra*" in your query, make sure that your (, ", ' etc...have matching pairs, because the error message in that case *is not relevant* and has nothing to do with your named parameter! JPA is right as it could not locate it, but that's because something else in your query is messing up...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it like this

where c.article_comment_id = ?,
 and c.any_other_field = ?;
....
query.setParameter(1, articleCommentId)
query.setParameter(2, anyOtherValue)

it will take it by sequence.

And you can also give numbers like

where c.article_comment_id = ?1,
 and c.any_other_field = ?2;
....
query.setParameter(1, articleCommentId)
query.setParameter(2, anyOtherValue)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using named parameter at end of your query the remove the ; from your query

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't add the extra space after the named parameter.

example:

```
  + "WHERE\n" + "    s.something = 'SOME'\n" + "START WITH\n"
                                        + "    s.country_type = :countryName" + "CONNECT BY\n"
                                        
changed to (notice the space after named parameter :countryName 

  + "WHERE\n" + "    s.something = 'SOME'\n" + "START WITH\n"
                                        + "    s.country_type = :countryName " + "CONNECT BY\n"
```